# Approach adviser to help publish a paper/Journal

Tags: advisor

> This topic may seem very close to [Unable to defend and graduate
>   because of advisers fickle mentality](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/unable-to-defend-and-graduate-because-of-advisers-fickle-mentality).

I am a Masters thesis student, and been doing my research for nearly 3 years now. Which I assume is quite long for Masters. So why such a long time. Well my adviser ( caring and supportive ) doesn't stick to or follow/have a structure for the thesis. Its like wandering about and finally OK yeah lets do this. Sometimes I face problems midway because we dint plan the thesis properly before hand and foresee what issues we could or would have to tackle way down the thesis, in which case it can be called more structured. Adding to this he is never present when needed.

In-spite of all these, I have somehow reached the very final stages of my thesis and trying to get some good results. I would like to open up and talk to him frankly and still maintain a good rapport so that I can ask to help me publish a paper/journal.

Could someone please give me a template of how I should approach him politely and convey my situation and get the best of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. You could say, "I think it would be a good idea to convert my thesis work into a journal paper. What do you think?"
2. Write up a version of the to-be-journal submission, present it to your supervisor, and ask "Do you think we could submit this, after some revision, to a journal?"

In any case, it sounds like you need to start being the master of your own destiny, and rely less on your supervisor. It is your masters' thesis after all, and your research.

Comment: He listens to only what "he wants". Discussion with him is nearly impossible, and not to mention he doesn't even reply to emails. Forget meeting face to face. How can I deal with this kind of adviser.

Comment: Submit your thesis and get out of there – surely someone higher up will be sympathetic to your plight. Also, write the research up later as a paper and try to submit somewhere, keeping your supervisor in the loop, but not as a barrier to progress.